# Using keys with spaces

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, dictionary, django-templates

Is there a way to do something like the following in Django templates?

```
   {% for hop in hops%}
    <tr>  
      <td>{{ hop.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ hop.mass }}</td>  
      <td>{{ hop."boil time" }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

The hop."boil time" doesn't work.  The simple solution is rename the key boil_time, but I'm interested in alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get at it is to sneak the property name into another variable, like so:

```
{% for key, value in hop.items %}
    {% ifequal key 'boil time' %}
        {{ value }}
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

In Django 0.96 (the version used by Google AppEngine) the templating language doesn't support tuple expansion, so it's a bit uglier:

```
{% for hop in hops %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ hop.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ hop.mass }}</td>
        <td>
            {% for item in hop.items %}
                {% ifequal item.0 'boil time' %}
                    {{ item.1 }}
                {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So, taking your code, we end up with:

```
{% for hop in hops %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ hop.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ hop.mass }}</td>
        <td>
            {% for key, value in hop.items %}
                {% ifequal key 'boil time' %}
                    {{ value }}
                {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In Django 0.96 (the version on Google AppEnginge), this becomes:

```
{% for hop in hops %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ hop.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ hop.mass }}</td>
        <td>
            {% for item in hop.items %}
                {% ifequal item.0 'boil time' %}
                    {{ item.1 }}
                {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

There's even a wordier way to get at it, using the regroup tag:

```
{% regroup hop.items by 'boil time' as bt %}
    {% for item in bt %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            {% for item2 in item.list %}
                {% for item3 in item2 %}
                    {% if not forloop.first %}
                        {{ item3 }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Django template language does not allow this.  The template language equivalent for `hop['boil time']` would be `hop.boil time` (which I think is the problem he is getting at).

Comment: Here's a reference for the comment I made above showing that the `.` notation covers indexes... http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Comment: I appreciate the effort to write out all of the code, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to work for me, event with copy and paste.  I can't get iteration over a dictionary to print any keys or values, even without an ifequals.

Comment: Dan, I actually tested the code on an instance I was running and it worked i both cases...  The only thing that I could think of is a problem with items.  Try just doing a {{ hop.items }}  to see what comes out.  If the dictionary had the items method overriden, that could cause issues  (e.g. hop has an 'items' property, then try hop.iteritems)

Comment: The google appengine uses Django 0.96, which doesn't support the key,value in dict.items syntax. http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/9160209ccfa94a30/492e6882bbc5e6e4?#492e6882bbc5e6e4

Comment: You can actually use Django 1.0 (or 1.1) on Google App Engine by specifying the version in your main.py: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `get` filter from djangosnippets: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1412/

(Renaming the key is probably better...)

Comment: I'll give that a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Man, I've been doing too much Ruby. My inclination is to monkeypatch `dict` to transform underscores into spaces...

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I'm using django templates in the google appengine, not a full django app.  There does not appear to be an easy way to add filters.

Answer (score 0):

For django 0.96, which is what the Google Appengine uses for templates, the following works:

```
{% for hop in recipe.get_hops %}
    {% for item in hop.items %}
          {% ifequal item.0 'boil time' %}
              <p>{{ item.1 }}</p>
          {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}   
  {% endfor %}
```

item.0 is the key and item.1 is the value.  [Link.](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/9160209ccfa94a30/492e6882bbc5e6e4?#492e6882bbc5e6e4)

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary keys contain spaces, you can still use Jinja templates with them. You can access dictionary keys with spaces using the [] syntax in the template.

Example:
{{ hop["boil time"] }}

Comment: A lot has changed in 13.5 years.